# 2 column listview within a 2 column list view

Tags: android

i want to put a 2 column listview in the 2nd column of my first 2 column listview but i dont know how to and is it possible to use the same code to make it a 3 column list view?where in the first column is an image and the 2nd and 3rd column are both text i tried it but it has error... my code goes like this..

main

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class WeatherToday extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_weathertoday);


    ListView view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.todaylist);
    final List<MyStringPair> myStringPairList = MyStringPair.makeData(10);
    MyStringPairAdapter adapter = new MyStringPairAdapter(this, myStringPairList);

    view.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

stringpairlist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyStringPair {

private String columnOne;
private String columnTwo;

public MyStringPair(String columnOne, String columnTwo) {
    super();
    this.columnOne = columnOne;
    this.columnTwo = columnTwo;


}

public String getColumnOne() {
    return columnOne;
}
public void setColumnOne(String columnOne) {
    this.columnOne = columnOne;
}
public String getColumnTwo() {
    return columnTwo;
}
public void setColumnTwo(String columnTwo) {
    this.columnTwo = columnTwo;
}


public static List<MyStringPair> makeData(int n) {
    List<MyStringPair> pair = new ArrayList<MyStringPair>();

        pair.add(new MyStringPair("Weather Condition", "Partly Cloudy"));
        pair.add(new MyStringPair("Temperature", "30 Celcius "));
        pair.add(new MyStringPair("Moisture", "Dew Point:" ));
        pair.add(new MyStringPair("Wind", "Column2 "));
        pair.add(new MyStringPair("Precipitation", "Column2 "));
        pair.add(new MyStringPair("Condition", "Pressure:1014 mb "));


    return pair;
}

}
```

adapter

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyStringPairAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private List<MyStringPair> stringPairList;


public MyStringPairAdapter(Activity activity, List<MyStringPair> stringPairList) {
    super();
    this.activity = activity;
    this.stringPairList = stringPairList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return stringPairList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return stringPairList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow, null);
    }

    TextView col1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.column1);
    TextView col2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.column2);
    col1.setText(stringPairList.get(position).getColumnOne());
    col2.setText(stringPairList.get(position).getColumnTwo());

    return convertView;
}
}
```

i've added a box on the column where i want another 2 column..basically i want to put two more column in the smaller box i want to divide the text into two parts so i need two columns for that but im out of ideas

[image]

Comment: Why dont you use a gridView?

Comment: because i only need two columns with multiple rows...and i'm a newbie in programming android i just copied the code from post here..

Comment: if you can provide an image depicting what u are trying to do, might be we can suggest something else.